# How to protect user specified table name from SQL Injection in C#, using MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-injection, mysql-connector

As a reaction to [MySqlParameter as TableName](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6041496/1380710), it seems that [MySQL's Connector/NET library](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) doesn't support table names from user input in the following way:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM @table");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@table",TableNameFromUserInput);
```

So I tried to find another way, but I couldn't find any libraries that did this for me.

When searching for how to do this manually, I couldn't found anything that didn't tell you to use "prepared statements" from some already defined library, no matter the language.

To my limited knowledge of SQL, I only think it's necessary to put backticks (`) around the user input and then check the input for backticks - but I wanted to be sure.

### Question

How do you protect a user specified table name from SQL-Injection when the MySQL Connector doesn't support it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if

```
TableNameFromUserInput
```

is an existing table, before executing the query.
That prevents other errors like "table doesnt exist" aswell.

Comment: I like this idea, because you can paramterize the table name for *this* command.

Comment: It seems like a possible solution, but it requires an additional query for all queries that use this query, and in my case it's going to be executed 10 times a second or more.

Comment: @Aske You can cache a list of existing table names - they won't change fast normally...

Answer (score 1):

you cannot add `tableName` (*as well as columnName*) as parameter in prepared statements because it only supports for a value. For your safety, add additional code to validate tableName, ex.

```
string tableName = "hello";
tableName = UDFunctionClean(tableName);
string query = String.Format("SELECT * FROM `{0}`", tableName);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query);
```

Comment: What should the `UDFunctionClean` do? Escape backticks and that's it?

Comment: maybe, actually its up to you, check for illegal characters such as single quote as tableName cannot contain single quotes.

Comment: Well, I don't care if they try to use a table called `\`; DROP Database dbName; SELECT * from \``, I just want to make it secure from non-standard requests. Are there any other ways to do SQL-injection than the backtick?

Comment: I realized I also needed to escape, escape characters (`\ `). Otherwise the user could just escape the first escape character (`\\`; Injected_Query_Here; SELECT * FROM \`table` turns into `SELECT * FROM \`\\\`; Injected_Query_Here; SELECT * FROM \`table\``).